# Replacement for Advanced Logging for IIS

Tags: iis, azure-monitoring

In most recent versions of IIS, Advanced logging is no longer supported.
I'm looking for an alternative, but the only thing I've been able to find is Enhanced Logging for IIS.
Unfortunately, this does not support filtering based on patterns (eg do not filter calls that end in .png or only filter calls that end in .asp).

The logs are picked up by the Microsoft Monitoring Agent and sent to an Azure Monitoring Workspace.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is filter the calls which end with .png or .asp. You can use "[Request Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/)" in IIS.

You can right click in "Request Filtering" page and "Allow File Name Extension" or "Deny File Name Extension" to add the specified extension which you want.

[image]

Comment: This will block certain files. That is not what we want. We just want to log certain files and ignore other logs.

Comment: Hi @Wouter I think it may be difficult to implement this requirement on IIS. Maybe you can filter the logs when query from azure monitor. For example [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/log-analytics-tutorial#multiple-query-conditions) a "where" condition in the query of logs.

Comment: That is not a good solution for us as we want to limit the amount of data that is ingested in Azure Monitor (because of the high cost).